# convertir archivo separado por | a xlsx con openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

si alguien me pudiera indicar por que al momento de convertir un archivo csv separado por | ,me arroja el error:

```
  File "D:\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX\extraccion_unica.py", line 32, in ObtenerUnica
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7307: character maps to <undefined>
```

Tengo la duda si es al especificar el delimitador '|', este es mi código:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open("D:/XXXXXXX/ResCargueUnica"+archivo_dia+".csv") as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = '|')
          for row in reader:
              ws.append(now)
wb.save('ResCargueUnica'+archivo_dia+'.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba añadiendo `, encoding='utf-8'` a la configuración de lectura de archivo

```
with open("D:/XXXXXXX/ResCargueUnica"+archivo_dia+".csv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = '|')
          for row in reader:
              ws.append(now)
wb.save('ResCargueUnica'+archivo_dia+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias me faltaba esa parte.

Comment: @FerneyGuerrero si te sirvió, recuerda marcarla como aceptada :)